# Python logging file creation fails when debugging in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-logging

I am trying to get simple debugging going in VS Code but am running into a slight issue.

When I run the below code using a normal python command in cmd (eg. python main.py), it runs perfectly. However, when I use the VS Code debugger to run the main.py file, it throws a  FileNotFoundError when trying to create a log file(logging module).  The file doesn't exist, but the "filemode" specifies that it should create the file if it can't find it:

```
logFileName = "foo.txt"

logger = logging.getLogger("MyLogger")
logging.basicConfig(filemode='w', level=logging.INFO,filename=logFileName,
           format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
```

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args" : ["release"],
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have configured VS Code to use python 3.7(the same as my cmd command) to ensure that is not the issue. Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I can't replicate the error, in my launch.json I do **not** use `pythonPath`. Make sure the `settings.json` contains the correct python exe.

Comment: Can you include the traceback you're getting?